# How to prove that a space is not a differential manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Given a box （the surface of a cubic） in R^3 space, can I give a smooth structure on it to make it a differential manifold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The box $B$ is homeomorphic to the $2$-sphere $S^2$, so you can choose a smooth structure on $S^2$ and a homeomorphism $f: B \to S^2$ and use that to transfer all your charts: a chart $\varphi : S^2 \supseteq V \to U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ becomes $\varphi \circ f$.

Transferring a smooth structure will result in a smooth structure, since if a transition function $\varphi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is smooth, then clearly $(\varphi \circ f) \circ (\psi \circ f)^{-1} = \varphi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is also smooth.

Comment: I come with another question here: how's the tangent vector like on the edge of the box? the box is embedded into R^3, so its tangent space should be a subspace of tangent space of R^3.

Comment: Generally speaking, followup questions like this aren't going to be answered. Instead, post another question, with a link back to this one and an explanation of the relation.